# How would I start to create this javascript structure using C# and MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Given a javascript data structure like this:

```
 var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
   ]
 };
```

How would I create this using MVC and C# from server side?

My guess is that it would be JSON data sent back in the action result of the controller.  Would there be a way to create a single class that contained all of these name value pairs that could easily be converted to JSON? The "data class" would contain a "Label class" and an enumeration of "datasets".  Each "dataset class" would have 8 properties as shown.

I'm fairly new to JSON from C# perspective...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a couple of classes to represent the above. The `DataContainer` class would be what your controllers return or take as a parameter. The `DataSet` class would contain the properties shown. I'm not sure what business domain this is for so you might want to choose more meaningful class names, but the below should give you a good starting point.

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public List<string> Labels { get; set; }
    public List<DataSet> DataSets { get; set; }
}

public class DataSet
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string FillColor { get; set; }
    public string StrokeColor { get; set; }
    public string PointColor { get; set; }
    public string PointStrokeColor { get; set; }
    public string PointHighlightFill { get; set; }
    public string PointHighlightStroke { get; set; }
    public List<int> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neil that's all I think I needed  because I have already discovered how to convert them to JSON...